# Fitting a power-law with powerlaw.py in Python 3

Tags: python, power-law

I am trying to fit power law with powerlaw.py:

```
data = [1.7, 3.2, 4.3, 2.1, 0.9, 3.3, 1.2, 4.3]
fit = powerlaw.Fit(data)
```

I'm getting the warning:

```
IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes
(and a single ...) as an index
```

I've tested also data which were used in [these code examples](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/bb4e1dfafd9e90d5bc3d) and I have always the same problem.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran code:

In [1]: import powerlaw

In [2]: data = [1.7, 3.2, 4.3, 2.1, 0.9, 3.3, 1.2, 4.3]

In [3]: fit = powerlaw.Fit(data)
Calculating best minimal value for power law fit
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerlaw-1.3-py2.7.egg/powerlaw.py:686: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  (Theoretical_CDF * (1 - Theoretical_CDF))

In [4]: fit.sigma
Out[4]: 0.37880479849893711

might want to check for a bug elsewhere... if not might be a version error

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to get the C - scaling factor?